# Validation using trigger?

Tags: trigger

I am trying to develop a validation rule for contact object using trigger. The trigger should validate if selected Account is Active or not on a Contact. Please review my code. How can I remove the SOQL out of the for loop?

```
trigger ValidateAccount on Contact (before insert,before update) {
    List<contact> coninsert = new List<contact>();
    List<Id> AccountCheck = new List<Id>();
    for(Contact con : Trigger.New){
        if(con.AccountId != null){
            string active = [Select Active__c from Account where id =: 
                             con.AccountId].Active__c ;
            if(Active == 'Yes'){
                coninsert.add(con);
                System.debug('Account is active');
            }
            else {
                con.addError('Bad data');
                System.debug('Account is not active');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a validation rule, or perhaps a lookup filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach will be like this. Better to put your logic in Trigger Handler.

```
trigger ValidateAccount on Contact (before insert,before update) {
    List<contact> coninsert = new List<contact>();
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

    //collect all accountId in Set
    for(Contact con : Trigger.New){
        accountIds.add(con.AccountId);      
    }

    //retrieve account details
    Map<Id,Account> mapAccount = [Select Id, Active__c from Account where id =: accountIds];


    //loop through the Contact records from trigger
    for(Contact con : Trigger.New){

        //retrieve the account record based on id.
        Account acct = mapAccount.get(con.AccountId);

        //compare the active value
        if(acct.Active__c == 'Yes')
        {
            coninsert.add(con);
            System.debug('Account is active');
        }
        else
        {
            con.addError('Bad data');
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: thank you. I will try using trigger handler in a apex class

Comment: For a good example of trigger handler done right:  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/units/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_dl_principles

Answer (score 4):

Using a trigger to accomplish this is overkill (that is, a trigger offers *substantially more power than you need*).

In cases like this, I would prefer using a validation rule or a lookup filter (as sfdcfox mentioned in the comments). In a validation rule (or a lookup filter), you are able to reference related objects (child to parent) using dot-notation (same as you would in Apex).

Your validation formula could look something like this:

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(AccountId)),
    Account.Active__c <> 'Yes'
)
```

The benefits to this approach  are:

- No unit test required (though you could still write test(s) for this, if you were so inclined)
- Should end up being shorter than any code you'd write to accomplish the same thing (generally speaking, shorter code = less chance for bugs)
- Easier to maintain (no deployment required)